# How can I extract the number of patients who use medications within 15 days before the surgery or within a 15 day days after the surgery in postgers

Tags: sql, postgresql

surgery table

```
pid surgeryName surgeryDate
1010    backsurgery 1/15/2018
2020    backsurgery 1/15/2016
2020    backsurgery 1/15/2016
2020    backsurgery 1/15/2016
2020    backsurgery 1/15/2016
2020    backsurgery 1/15/2016
```

medication table

```
pid-2   medicationName  medicationDate
1010    MED2    1/1/2016
2020    MED3    1/1/2018
2020    mmm 1/5/2016
2020    mmm 1/5/2013
2020    mmm 2/10/2016
2020    mmm 2/10/2018
```

How can I extract the number of patients who use medications within 15 days before the surgery or within a 15 day days after the surgery.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using postgres and how can I extract the list of pid  who use medications within 15 days before the surgery or within a 15 day days after the surgery 


select * from "TEST".surgery s
inner join "TEST".medication m on m.pid = s.pid
where   s."surgeryDate"  between date_trunc('day' , m."medicationDate") - interval '15days' 
and date_trunc('day' , m."medicationDate") + interval '15days'


error date_trunc unknown 

if you have any way to extract please tell